# Custom calendar system for vaadin DateField

Tags: vaadin7, gregorian-calendar, datefield, hijri

The Vaadin DateField uses the **Calendar.getInstance()**, (Gregorian calendar).

Is there a way to use Custom (e.g: Hijri) calendar system?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not in standard java.util.*-classes based on `Calendar`. JDK only offers gregorian, thai-buddhist and japanese-imperial, not more.

You might consider ICU4J which offers an algorithmic variation of Hijri calendar. A similar but weaker solution is Joda Time (without real support for hijri month names).

A sighting-based calendar like umalqura-calendar will only be offered in Java 8 with the new date-time-api (JSR-310).